When using Jest-Cucumber with Jest and React Testing Library I get ReferenceError: _react1 is not defined
I am trying to test form inputs and button clicks with the screen object from React Testing Library and getting the following error when using Jest-Cucumber with React Testing Library: ReferenceError: _react1 is not defined
Here's a simplified version of my test:
import React from 'react';
import { defineFeature, loadFeature } from 'jest-cucumber';
import { render, screen, fireEvent, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import LoginPage from '@/app/[locale]/(public)/login/page';

const feature = loadFeature('__test__/auth/login/login.feature');

defineFeature(feature, (test) => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            render(<LoginPage />);
        });
    });

    test('Login form works', ({ when }) => {
        when('I enter credentials', async () => {
            const emailInput = await screen.findByLabelText('E-Mail Adresse');
            fireEvent.input(emailInput, { target: { value: 'test@example.com' } });
            expect(emailInput).toHaveValue('test@example.com');
        });
    });
});

The Error:
When I try to access the screen object (e.g., screen.findByLabelText), I get the error:
ReferenceError: _react1 is not defined

I ensured that React is imported properly at the top of the test file.
Verified that screen is from @testing-library/react.
Confirmed that Jest is correctly configured for TypeScript and React.

Anyone else has had this issue? Anything I should look into in the Jest or TypeScript configuration?
Any help would be appreciated!

Hey, it looks like something bad happened with transpilation (babel, or whatever is used). May you show your tooling configurations?

I'm using the default babel configuration in NextJS, I haven't changed anything there. As a matter of fact, simple Jest test files work perfectly...
